# Как составить web.xml для фильтра?

Tags: servlet, кодировка, java, tomcat, web.xml

Здравствуйте. Потихоньку учу сервлеты, в данный момент имею такую вещь:

```
package app01a;
import ...

@WebServlet(name = "HelloServlet", urlPatterns = { "/my" })
public class HelloServlet implements Servlet {

 ...

 @Override
 public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {
   String servletName = servletConfig.getServletName();
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
   PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
   writer.print("<html><head></head>"
   + "<body>Привет от " + servletName + " " + request.getParameter("name")
   + "</body></html>");
 }

}
```

Обращаюсь к нему с таким запросом:

> [http://localhost:8080/app2/my?name=привет](http://localhost:8080/app2/my?name=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82)

На выходе получаю:

> Привет от HelloServlet Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ

Умные люди на всех сайтах советуют писать фильтр, например, на [стаковерфлоу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps) приводят его код и кусок кода для web.xml:

```
<!--CharsetFilter start--> 

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>fi.foo.filters.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Как видно из HelloServlet.java, я использую аннотации, поэтому сейчас файла web.xml у меня просто нет. А если я его добавляю, что бы я ни пытался туда написать, страница http://localhost:8080/app2/my становится недоступна. Я знаю, что для решения этой проблемы мне нужно просто-напросто дальше продолжать читать свою книгу, но очень хочется на текущем этапе получить сервлет, корректно работающий с кириллицей в utf-8. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно настроить фильтр (составить web.xml) в моей ситуации?

**Обновление**

Сейчас вот составил web.xml, убрал аннотацию в HelloServlet.java, и вроде работает, но вместо русских букв всё равно ерунда.

Comment: Прикольно конечно читать, каким образом я общался 8 лет назад)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче заново скачал Tomcat, удалил старую папку conf, заменил на новую, потом в server.xml дописал в Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" и всё, всё заработало.